# Shape key edit mode, transform handles not located at selected vert

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms, shape-keys

Armature character mesh posed into position. made shape key. enter edit mode. click a vert, the movement handles are located at the mesh's original position, pre-armature in the stack. floating in midair where the mesh used to be, not where the selected vert currently is (in its posed position). the transform handle can be selected and moved, but it moves based on its un-posed position, sometimes moving the edited vert upside down or backwards based on the previous position, which makes it impossible to edit with any predictability (move a vert, but it sometimes moves in the opposite direction).

I made a new test box, applied a modifier of displace, added a shape key, enter edit mode, select a vert corner, its doing the same thing. showing the move handle where it was before it currently is in the stack.

What can be done? I can't find anyone else with this problem.

Seems to be a normal function, but I can't imagine because then it's completely useless. Arent you supposed to see the current armature pose when editing a shape key?? How can you guess the desired position of verts pre-posed. Is this seemingly worthless functionality considered normal.

Here is example cube, much worse/further away on posed armature:

[image]

Comment: so is this supposed to happen? is this common? if so, is there any way to keep reassigning a new default pose or something like that with the edit mode pose to get the verts to line up? or does this bug need to be reported to blender